# How to import cell value to array to insert into a DB or an object?

Tags: c#, excel

I am working on how to import information from an excel file to different tables in a DB, the problem is that I have implemented the following code, but at the time of executing it I can not see if I have correctly read the information in the cells, now After reading them I want to start categorizing what information interests me, then choose what information I should insert into an object or a DB

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WebApplication2
{
   public class ImportExcel
   {


    public void GetValuesExcel()
    {

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\JULIO.xlsx");
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets[1];
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;


        int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
        int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;


        for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
            {
                //new line
                if (j == 1)
                    Console.Write("\r\n");

                //write the value to the console
                if (xlRange.Cells[i, j] != null)
                    Console.Write(xlRange.Cells[i, j].ToString() + "\t");
            }
        }

        //cleanup
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        //rule of thumb for releasing com objects:
        //  never use two dots, all COM objects must be referenced and released individually
        //  ex: [somthing].[something].[something] is bad

        //release com objects to fully kill excel process from running in the background
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);

        //close and release
        xlWorkBook.Close();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);

        //quit and release
        xlApp.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
    }

    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetValuesExcel();

    }
   }
 }
```

The excel table contains the following rows:

1. Package
2. Number
3. Username
4. Creation
5. date
6. cost
7. Departure date
8. Arrival date

Comment: Sorry, what's your question? I don't quite understood

Comment: How do I save it in an array, all the information you get from excel? In an array or in a hashmap to know that information to which column belongs

Comment: You're reading the cell value and printing in the console, why not just assign its value to an array element, like `myArray[i,j]=xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString()`, where myArray is an `string[,]`? PS: I didn't test your code, but shouldn't it use the Value property like I did in the example?

Comment: Yes, I do want to save it in an array in a structure that then allows me to iterate in the registers, which I recommend and if they have some tip I would be grateful